# build software from source code and install it in custom folder on Linux

Tags: linux, bash, compiler-construction, installation

I want to compile and build a software from its source. Then, install it in user folder. because I don't have administrator privilege, so I can't install from the software's binary package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to install a software called 'test'.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Set this to where you want to install all the software
PREFIX=/usr/oma/sardar/software

export CC=/usr/bin/gcc
export CXX=/usr/bin/g++
export QTDIR=/usr/lib/qt-4.6
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=$PREFIX/lib/pkgconfig

# Get sources
mkdir -p $PREFIX/src/{BUILD,SOURCES}
wget -U temp -P $PREFIX/src/SOURCES http://url/test.tar.gz
wget -P $PREFIX/src/SOURCES http://url/test.patch

# Unpack sources

tar xvzf $PREFIX/src/SOURCES/test.tar.gz -C $PREFIX/src/BUILD

# Compile Test

cd $PREFIX/src/BUILD/test
patch < $PREFIX/src/SOURCES/test.patch
(
    export CFLAGS="-I$PREFIX/include"
    export LDFLAGS="-L$PREFIX/lib -Wl,-R$PREFIX/lib"
    ./configure --prefix=$PREFIX
)
make
make install
```